# How to install libquicktime on CentOS 7 in one (or two) line of command?

Tags: installation, centos, rpm, quicktime

For some reason, I need support of QuickTime on my CentOS 7. So I searched the internet and found that something called "`libquicktime`" can provide that support. So I download the rpm file from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libquicktime%28x86-64%29. Then I ran command `rpm -i libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64.rpm` and got the following errors:

```
warning: libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 66534c2b: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libfaac.so.0()(64bit) is needed by libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64
    libfaad.so.2()(64bit) is needed by libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64
    libmp3lame.so.0()(64bit) is needed by libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64
    libquicktime.so.0()(64bit) is needed by libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64
    libschroedinger-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64
    libx264.so.142()(64bit) is needed by libquicktime-1.2.4-31.el7.x86_64
```

I can install these missing dependencies by querying for their package name and install them one by one **manually**. But this is so tedious and time consuming, so I am wondering if there is any one-strike single-line (or two) command that can automatically install all dependencies, as well as the target rpm file. I hear that yum has a similar function but I don't know how to use yum to install `libquicktime` because it complains "No package libquicktime available."

Thanks for any (working) answer.

PS: I'm using CentOS 7, so please don't point me to those too old CentOS 6 links. I've read them, they are only a waste of time on 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(aside)
Some versions of rpm (but not you on Centos 7) can add missing dependencies when given a database of "everything" including paths to download the package from.

On Centos 7, yum is the best answer. You would need to configure a local repository in /etc/yum.repos.d/something pointing to a local repository.

The local repository (i.e. a local directory somewhere) should contain the libquicktime package, and you need to run createrepo in that directory to generate the repository metadata that yum uses to build a transaction.